# Caesar cipher and reverse text program

Tags: c, string, pointers, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a function that gets a string and a number and if the number is bigger the '0' so it will make the caesar cipher with the string and the number that the user entered. 
for example -> 'stack' and the number is '3' -> 'uvdfn'.
if the number is '0' so it will reverse the string.
for example - 'stack' -> 'kcats'

I don't know what is the issue with the code, i don't see anything wrong.

```html
/*********************************
* Class: MAGSHIMIM C2    *
* Week 3                         *
**********************************
* Thank you for Ofek and Dor for *
* Editing this template :)       *
**********************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void decryptText(char* encText, int n);

#define STR_SIZE 50
int main(void)
{
 char str[STR_SIZE];
 int num = 0;

 printf("Please enter the string : ");
 fgets(str, STR_SIZE, stdin);

 printf("Please enter a number : ");
 scanf("%d", &num);

 decryptText(str, num);

    system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}


void decryptText(char* encText, int n)
{
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 char temp = 0;

 int strLen = strlen(encText);

 if (n > 0)
 {
  for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
  {
   if (*(encText + i) == ' ') { }
   else
   {
    if (*(encText + i) >= 'x')
    {
     *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) - 26;
    }
    *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) + n;
   }
  }

  printf("The array after the program deciphered it : \n");
  printf("%s", encText);
 }

 else if (n == 0)
 {
  for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
  {
   for (j = 0; j >= 0; j--)
   {
    temp = *(encText + i);
    *(encText + i) = *(encText + j);
    *(encText + i) = temp;
   }
  }

  printf("The array after the program cracked it : \n");
  printf("%s", encText);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When reversing the string you are swapping letters from front to back and then from back to front and so you end up with the same string that you started with. You also don't need to use all the pointers because you can use array subscripting which makes it more readable. Try something more like this:

```
j = strLen-1;
for (i = 0; i < strLen/2; i++, j--) {
    temp = encText[i];
    encText[i] = encText[j];
    encText[j] = temp;
}
```